# Latin expression for the advantage of being possession of disputed goods in a civil suit?

Tags: from-the-latin

Some time ago I saw (In fact it might have been in a comic, possibly Zits.) an expression/proverb that basically said that being in possession of disputed goods meant that a civil lawsuit/quarrel was almost won before it had begun. Anyone know what idiom I am talking about and can remind me?

NB: I am not sure if it was in English or Latin. If possible I would prefer a Latin answer.

Edit: after learning about this nine-tenths idiom I found two similar latin expressions, *possidetis, ita possideatis* and *qui tenet teneat, qui dolet doleat*. Are there more or better latin expressions I should be aware of?

Comment: 'Possession is nine tenths of the law'?

Comment: @flup yeah, that's what I would've said. But it's not a very exciting answer unless the answer is also about how it's literally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The only expression I'm aware of is: ***possession is nine-tenths of the law***.

This expression does not hold up literally; *title* is much stronger evidence than possession.

*Uti possidetis, ita possideatis* is a principle of **international law**. This applies to relations between sovereign states, rather than private individuals. It relates to the acquisition of territory following conflict.

*Qui tenet teneat, qui dolet doleat* is a different matter - although it's a reasonably well-known Latin expression, it's not been used in law [since 1286](http://www.bu.edu/phpbin/lawyearbooks/display.php?id=327).

Although these Latin expressions exist, they don't really hold any legal force, and I wouldn't try to use them in a court. They're good for impressing friends at a party, though.

Comment: Another latin expression I found *beati possidentes*. Anyway, I am not gonna use them in the american legal system but in a completely different context.

Comment: There's no title in a leasehold; but "keys =  possession" is a typical expression on landlord forums.  If the tenant still has the keys, you put yourself at great risk if you pursue "self-help" eviction steps; and explains the motivation for the "cash for keys" exit from a disputed lease.

Comment: @user662852 As the question referred to "goods", I assumed moveable goods rather than real property (I've never heard them called such).